# What did I do WRONG?

Tags: images

WHAT did I do WRONG?

I am most definitely NOT skilled with website building, but I try to do things on my own.

I know ABSOLUTELY NOTHING about code and working with code.

I decided to change the look of my wordpress website.

I setup a NEW site on my hosting account.

I set up a staging site for the new site on my host account.

I used the SAME THEME as my present site and totally redesigned it on the new staging site.

I duplicated MANY (but not all because I had too many) of the same plugins from the existing site to the new staging site.

I IMPORTED all of my posts and pages from the existing site to the new staging site.

I IMPORTED my entire existing media library to the new staging site.

I copied and placed the widgets used on the existing site to the new staging site.

When it looked the way I wanted it to look, I then moved the new staging site to the new site I setup on my hosting account and checked it again and it looked and functioned the way I wanted it to.

I then had my host remove the existing site FOR ME and replace it with the new version of the site and it became the active site.

NOW when I open the site ALL of the images are NOT THERE and they ONLY SHOW UP WHEN THE CURSOR IS PLACED DIRECTLY OVER THEM.

BUT the pictures on the widgets do not show up AT ALL.

WHAT SETTING DO I HAVE TO CHANGE TO GET THE IMAGES TO APPEAR PERMANENTLY?

Comment: Did you do a search and replace on the database to change the site from your staging URL (https://your-staging-domain.com) to your live domain (https://your-live-domain.com)?

Comment: Can you please reformat your question to make it more readable? We don't care about your background, important is what you did, what the status is now and what it should be. Try avoiding putting EVERYTHING IN CAPSLOCK please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in one of the comments to your question, the issue is how WP stored images (which are actually a kind of post).  If you look at the Media on your developement/local site, you will see that each image has a URL that is related to your local URL.

And each image is stored in a folder (you can see the folder name in the URL). So, there  are two things you have to do if you want the images from your development site available on the live site.e

You have to manually copy the images from the development folders to the same folders on the live site.

And you have to replace the URLs inside the database for those media items to point to the new URL. This is most easily done with a Search and Replace plugin (I like the "Better Search and Replace" plugin).  Use the plugin to search for your old domain/URL (the test system) and replace it with the new/live domain name/URL. (You can do this also with manual SQL commands, but the plugins are easier.)

Once you do that, the new images should be visible.

And, please, no all caps. It looks like you are shouting, and it's hard to read.

Comment: Great answer. Just to add, if you're having difficulties accessing /wp-admin to install the "Better Search and Replace" plugin, try this search and replace solution: https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases. Uploading this script to your site will allow you to visit the tool outside WordPress to perform a search and replace. When the search and replace is complete, it's VERY important to remove the tool.

Comment: Thank you.  Sorry about the caps.  I was trying to explain everything as thoroughly as I could.  I will try both of these suggestions.